# Tkinter showing images

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Here is the code I am trying to display images.
Well.. first of all there should be 4 cards shown in the screen ; however,  there are only 2.
I have no idea why this is happening. I really need help .

```
def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.master.title("Black Jack")
    blackjack = Blackjack()
    self.grid()

    self._playerCardImage = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._player._cards[0].fileName))
    self._playerCardLabel = Label(self, image = self._playerCardImage)
    self._playerCardLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)


    self._playerCardImage1 = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._player._cards[1].fileName))
    self._playerCardLabel1 = Label(self, image = self._playerCardImage1)
    self._playerCardLabel1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    self._dealerCardImage = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._dealer._cards[0].fileName))
    self._dealerCardImage = Label(self, image = self._dealerCardImage)
    self._dealerCardImage.grid(row=0, column=2)

    self._dealerCardImage1 = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._dealer._cards[1].fileName))
    self._dealerCardImage1 = Label(self, image = self._dealerCardImage1)
    self._dealerCardImage1.grid(row=0, column=3)
```

Answer (score 4):

your first 2 lines of code for the first 2 cards:

```
self._playerCardImage = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._player._cards[0].fileName))
self._playerCardLabel = Label(self, image = self._playerCardImage)
self._playerCardLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

your last 2 lines of code for the last 2 cards:

```
self._dealerCardImage1 = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._dealer._cards[1].fileName))
self._dealerCardImage1 = Label(self, image = self._dealerCardImage1)
self._dealerCardImage1.grid(row=0, column=3)
```

you are reinitializing the `_dealerCardImage1` as a label.
you will need to change the alst 2 lines to something like:

```
self._dealerCardImage1 = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._dealer._cards[1].fileName))
self._dealerCardLabel1 = Label(self, image = self._dealerCardImage1)
self._dealerCardLabel1.grid(row=0, column=3)
```

Comment: Oh gosh.. my bad. Careless mistakes ! Thank you!

Comment: @user1047092 no problem :), remember to mark answers as well, it will make people want to help you more.

Comment: I just have another question in mind. Right now I am trying to display 4 images. Is there a way to display image without having to write repetitive codes like above?

Comment: @user1047092 Not to my knowledge, but if you post a separate question with that content someone might be able to answer.

Comment: @user1047092: of course there is. There's nothing different about writing code in a loop versus duplicating the code.

Comment: @Serdalis: I don't understand what you wrote. All I know is, I've written 100's of thousands of lines of GUI code in my career (hand-written, not generated by a GUI design tool), and I create widgets in loops all the time. There's nothing hard or special about it. In this particular case, there's simply no reason not to create all of the cards in a loop.

Comment: @Serdalis: I don't know what you mean by "batch operations" That phrase doesn't seem to make any sense in the context of tkinter and python, and seems completely unrelated to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

In a question to another answer you asked if you could create the images in a loop. There's nothing to prevent you from doing just that.

For example, if you wanted to create 4 player cards, you could do something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.master.title("Black Jack")
    blackjack = Blackjack()
    self.grid()

    self._images = []
    self._labels = []
    for column in range(4):
        image = PhotoImage(file=str(blackjack._player._cards[column].fileName))
        label = Label(self, image = image)
        label.grid(row=0, column=column)

        self._images.append(image)
        self._labels.append(label)
```